# DIV Simplesmente Sumindo?

Tags: html, css, div

Estava montando um website para um servidor de minecraft. Porém me deparei com algo muito estranho.
Eu utilizo o Brackets para criar páginas HTML, e assim eu utilizo a ferramenta live preview.
Ao colocar um botão no HTML e modificá-lo no CSS, tudo ficou ok no live preview. Porém ao apertar F5 o botão simplesmente desaparece da página e do próprio HTML do site.
Vou mandar o arquivo HTML e o CSS.

index.html

```
<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>

        <!-- Definindo charset -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Linkando CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">

        <!-- Titulo da pagina -->
        <title>Bem Vindo - CraftDraw</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Imagem -->
        <div id="imagem">

        <img src="img/minecraft.png" />

        </div>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div id="menu">

            <iframe src="template/menu.html" width="100%" height="12%" frameborder="0" />

        </div>

        <!-- Botão VIP -->
        <div id="vip">

            <p>

                <a href="vip.html">
                    Compre Seu VIP
                </a>

            </p>

        </div>

</body>
```

index.css

```
/* Imagem */
#imagem img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* Menu */
#menu iframe {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Botão VIP */
#vip p a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 3;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: bisque;
    font-family: "Trebucher MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#vip p a:hover {
    background-color: #474646;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: aquamarine;
    color: aqua;
}
```

style.css

```
/* Body padrão */
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Menu */
#menu iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

O resultado e isso:
[image: Imagem 1]

[image: Imagem 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você não está fechando o iframe apropriadamente, o browser está ignorando a barra que você colocou no final do elemento e está considerando o resto da página como continuação do seu conteúdo. Colocar a barra no final do elemento só é considerado válido em tags que não precisam ser fechadas.

Referência e mais informações:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5 e https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#self-closing-start-tag-state

Comment: Cara vlw era realmente isso. Porem estou com uma outra duvida da uma olhada lá :). http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122782/body-vazia-no-final-da-p%C3%A1gina